# DRF JWT Don't require token on OPTIONS-requests

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, jwt

How can you make JWT not check and require a token when user does an OPTIONS-request?

I have defined my own `options(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method, but as long as the `permission_classes = [isAuthenticated]` is enabled, the user is asked to provide login credentials...

The API we are using in React to interact with DRF has to do an OPTION-request, which does not contain any headers. When it does not get a 200 code back, it does not perform the actual request to the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple way is to declare [custom permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) and use it (in a permissions.py file):

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsAuthenticated(permissions.IsAuthenticated):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return True
        return super(IsAuthenticated, self).has_permission(request, view)
```

and in the settings change the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to this class...

Comment: provide the error message please, and i think your correct way is override the `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` [get_jwt_value method](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L81)

Comment: There is no error-code, I just get a 401 response with "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." from JWT.

Comment: the message generated by condition in the line 93 i think you can override it, i added to the answer example.

Comment: I am afraid this did not work either. As seen in the source-code, none of these functions return "    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." " as the message alongside the 401...

Comment: As seen here, the error-message is not listed in the JWT-messages file: https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

Comment: I solved it by overriding the IsAuthenticated class in backend.permissions and set the default permission class to that in settings.py.

Comment: you can edit the answer for other whow will search the solution